# json-rpc response jq filtering with multiple possible values

Tags: json, jq, json-rpc

Can't figure how to filter jq output to show only result or error message from json-rpc response. Example response looks like this:

Normal:

```
{
  "result": "0001",
  "id": 1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": -32000,
    "message": "Server error",
    "data": {
      "type": "TypeError",
      "args": [
        "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"
      ],
      "message": "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"
    }
  },
  "id": 1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

I can access both of them alone, but don't know how to get 'or' function

```
$ ./reqok | jq .result
"0001"
$ ./reqbad | jq .error.data.message
"'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `jq` you can use the alternate operator `//` that can be used to return default values. E.g. A filter of the form `a // b` produces the same results as `a`, if `a` produces results other than `false` and `null`. Otherwise, `a // b` produces the same results as `b`.

Also useful for providing defaults: `.foo // 1` will evaluate to `1` if there’s no `.foo` element in the input.

```
jq '.result? // .error.data.message?'
```

Note that this will *only* work when the the value of `.result` isn't `null` or `false` in which case also the execution goes the alternate condition.

Comment: result sometimes can be null or false, so i believe that safer in my case will be "jq '.error.data.message? // .result?" Thx !

Comment: If the error message can be null too you could chain a third alternative, e.g. `.result? // .error.data.message? // "null or false result or error message"`

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, the result is a JSON object, so you could avoid the null/false issue that arises using // by checking whether the object has an "error" key, along the lines of:

```
if has("error") then ... else ... end
```

Of course this approach can also incorporate the use of `//` and `?`, etc.